# nox-classic : Could not find a version of the library

Tags: controller, openflow, sdn, pox

How can I install `nox-classic` on Ubuntu14.04 (32bit)?

I installed packages first:

```
sudo apt-get install nox-dependencies
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-serialization-dev libboost-all-dev
```

I then ran `../configure` and received the following output and error:

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.34.1... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!
```

I also tried

- `../configure --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
- changing `pkglib` to `pkgdata` in `src/Make.vars`

but neither solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I formatted your code using backticks, include the command lines.  This should make them easier to read.  I also moved the goal to the top of the post so that folks reading the question will immediately know what you are trying to accomplish.  If you need a reference to formatting, please see [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  Also check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Thanks for your question - hope you get some good answers!